# Reverse an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, nsdictionary, reverse

My case is that I have an array and the problem is that is has everything backwards like this

```
let array:[String] = ["image4", "image3", "image2", "image1"]
```

I need to change it so that it can display like 1,2,3,4 instead of 4,3,2,1 because right now it goes from oldest to newest, the opposite of what I want.

I noticed that there is an instance method called reversed() that perhaps could work with this but I'm not sure how to implement it in this situation. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: `let array = ["image4", "image3", "image2", "image1"]` and if you need the same elements in reverse order `let reversed = array.reversed()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var newArray = Array(array.reversed())
```

array.reversed() returns a structure of type ReversedCollection that you can use to initialise an actual array with Array().

Comment: Note that reversed() is O(1) if you initialize a new array with it it will become O(n)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't rely on it being in some order, sort it.

```swift
array.sorted()
```

Comment: this sort wont work if there are more than 10  elements when sorting string with numbers